# Вопрос про Google Maps Javascript API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Нужно создать HTML страницу с 2мя input, в первый input вводим адрес и во второй. Отображается [карта Google](https://maps.google.com/) как на картинке:
[image: Карты Google - Маршруты]
Главное, чтобы показывало маршрут от точки А до точки Б + считало точный километраж.
Затем нужно будет добавить возможность нажимать по ссылке "Добавить пункт назначения", чтобы добавить дополнительный input. Тогда уже маршрут будет не из двух точек, а из трех А, Б и В. Как лучше реализовать данную задачу? Можно ли такое реализовать с помощью АПИ Яндекс Карт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что имеется ввиду под вопросом "Как лучше реализовать данную задачу"? 
По второму - можно на любом АПИ сделать это. В АПИ гугла и яндекса есть расчёт маршрута движения по любому количеству точек. Только не советую вбивать полный адрес, а лучше, по каждому адресу в геокодере искать координаты точки и затем прокладывать маршрут по координатам. 
Для гугл.карт ищите методы начинающиеся с Directions... , в яндекс.картах route.